# How to select a specific HTML page through JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Does anyone know how to write a function to select a specific page in JavaScript? The reason why I am asking is because I have multiple projects that use the same base master pages and placeholders. I need to be able to change some of the project's individual pages (CSS & HTML) with out changes applying to all of the pages in the particular project.

My JavaScript code:

```
function InitPage() {
    $('div#rightContent img').replaceWith('<img src="newpicfile.jpg">');
}
```

The problem with the above code is it changes all of the divs with the id of `rightContent`. I just need it to target one page in particular.

Comment: You could always test the window location and then run the function.

Comment: ...or add an id to your body tags and include that...

Answer (score 2):

Place this in the code -

```
function InitPage() {    
    if("http://mydomain.com/page.html" == location.href) {
         $('div#rightContent img').replaceWith('<img src="newpicfile.jpg">');
    }
}
```

Comment: Glad that I could help. Please accept the answer if you're happy with it.